# Numerical integration for simulation of rigid body using euler parameters

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am trying to numerically integrate the following equation of motion and solve for $\boldsymbol\omega $  vector(3x1) :
$$\textbf{M} = [I]\dot{\boldsymbol\omega} + \tilde{\boldsymbol\omega}[I]\boldsymbol\omega $$
$$\dot{\boldsymbol\omega} = [I]^{-1}(\textbf{M} - \tilde{\boldsymbol\omega}[I]\boldsymbol\omega) $$

So the above equation is I want to numerically integrate given initial $\boldsymbol\omega_0$ vector, inertia matrix(=identity matrix) and moment vector(=zero vector).

At the moment I am trying to use **odeint** from scipy but it throws me an **ValueError: Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional.**

Here is my approach

```
I = np.array([[10, 0, 0], [0, 15, 0], [0, 0, 20]]) 
C0 = np.eye(3)
M = np.zeros(3).reshape(3, 1)
I_inv = np.linalg.inv(I)

def skew(x):
    return np.array([[0, -x[2], x[1]],
                     [x[2], 0, -x[0]],
                     [-x[1], x[0], 0]])
def model(w, t):
    H = np.matmul(I, w) #angular momentum
    A = M - np.matmul(skew(w), H)
    
    dwdt = np.matmul(I_inv, A)
    
    return dwdt

#Initial condition
w0 = np.array([0.01, 10, 0]).reshape(3, 1)

#time points
t = np.linspace(0, 20)

#solve ode
w = odeint(model, np.hstack(w0), t)
```

I have never used odeint with matrix equations so I am not sure if I am using the right integration method for the equation. How can resolve this using odeint or should I use a different integration method?

I am also open to MATLAB hints or answers.

Notations:

1. $\textbf{A}$ - 3x1 vector
2. $[I]$ - 3x3 matrix
3. $\tilde{A}$ -skew symmetric matrix

Comment: This would be a better fit for https://scicomp.stackexchange.com or https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: I think that odint just work for scalar ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my MATLAB code

```
function omp=myode(om,t,I,M)
omp=I^(-1)*(M-cross(om,I*om));
 
%main Program
clear all
close all
clc
om=zeros(3,1);
I= [[10, 0, 0]; [0, 15, 0]; [0, 0, 20]];
M=[1,0,3]';
y0=[0.01, 10, 0];
tspan=[0 15]; 
F_ode=@(t,y)myode(om,t,I,M);
option=odeset('MaxStep',0.04);
[t,y] =ode45(F_ode,tspan,y0,option); 
plot(t,y);
```

[image]